# What does negative probability represent?

Tags: quantum-state, photonics, contextuality, wigner-function

> "Negative energies and probabilities should not be considered as nonsense. They are well-defined concepts mathematically, like a negative of money." -[Paul Dirac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_probability)

The abstract from [Photon-phonon-photon transfer in optomechanics](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep46764) states:

> the Wigner function of the recovered state can have negative values at the origin, which is a manifest of nonclassicality of the quantum state

I recently learned about the Wigner function from [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/2479/2645) to a question I had asked about quantum shadowgraphy in which [Ernesto](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/2558/ernesto-galv%C3%A3o) says:

> there are quantum states for which the Wigner function may be negative in some phase-space regions! This is an indication of non-classicality
>   ... this negativity has been linked to contextuality

From [an answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/1641/2645) by [Rob](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/278/rob):

> experimental schemes to reconstruct the generalized Wigner representation of a given density operator (representing mixed or pure quantum states)

The abstract from [Negativity and contextuality are equivalent notions of nonclassicality](https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.5549) states

> We also demonstrate the impossibility of noncontextuality or nonnegativity in quantum theory

---

**What is negative probability?** Non-classicality? (Non)contextuality? Quasiprobability? <strike>Arbitrary multispin quantum states?</strike>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is non-classicality?

I'm not sure if there's a universally accepted definition, but the way that I'd define it is: if all possible outcomes of experiments on a particular quantum system can be described by a probability distribution, then the system is classical. Otherwise, it is non-classical. In alternative terminology, for a classical system, people say that there's a (local) hidden variable model that explains the experimental outcomes.

A trivial example is a diagonal density matrix when measured in the computational basis. The diagonal elements just give the probabilities of the different outcomes, so the state is classical.

> What is negative probability?

This is rather loose terminology. For a true probability distribution (in the discrete setting, a set $\{p_i\}$ such that $p_i\geq 0$ and $\sum_ip_i=1$) never contains negative probabilities by definition.

You only get "negative probability" in some quasi-probability distributions, and so it should probably be called "negative quasi-probability" to avoid misunderstandings. As stated in the question, this is one way of detecting non-classicality. That leads us to...

> What is quasi-probability?

(which may be what you're meaning by pseudoprobability). These are distributions that behave a lot like probabilities in many ways, but relax at least one of the constraints in the definition, usually the non-negativity of the elements. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiprobability_distribution), any density matrix can be written as a diagonal matrix using an over-complete basis. Those diagonal elements then form a quasi-probability distribution - some of the elements can be negative.

> What is (non)-contextuality?

Contextuality is another test that can be used to prove the non-classicality of a quantum system. This is a substantial topic that I'm not inclined to address in answer to small part of a question. You probably want to start finding out about the [Kochen-Specker Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kochen%E2%80%93Specker_theorem).

It is worth noting that Bell tests, such as the [CHSH test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHSH_inequality), can be considered as contextuality tests, they're just made a little simpler because they're supplemented with some extra information about non-locality between certain measurement operators, ensuring their commutation. So, with CHSH, you evaluate some expectation value $S$. If $|S|\leq 2$, the state is classical, while if $|S|>2$, it cannot be explained by a local hidden variable model; the state is non-classical.